# How to initialize a view in an Android Method?

Tags: java, android, methods, view, android-view

I am working on an Android Application that will take the height and weight of a person and calculates its BMI and Required calories based on Gender and Age.

When I press calculate button, the onClick method should be activated and thus there is another method called in the implementation of the 1st method.
The problem is that they are asking me to initialize the view and I dont know what do they mean and how to initialize in this case.

here's my java code for this:

```
public void calculateCalories()//this is the onClick method
{
    View view;
    onRadioButtonClicked(view); // here I get the error
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view)
{
    boolean checked=((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.male:
            if (checked)
                male_calories();
            break;
        case R.id.female:
            if (checked)
                female_calories();
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: On click method should contain view calculat Calories(View view) and you can pas to onradioclikedbutton

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your Java code doesn't know which of your activity views is your checkbox, that's why you are getting an error.
The common practice to initialise a view is writing this line in onCreate method:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yourcheckboxname);
```

Then to add listener:

```
cb.addOnCheckChanged(this);
```

and implement onCheckChanged within your Java class.

And you don't need to manually call onCheckChanged() - it's fired automatically everytime user checks or unchecks the checkbox